# “Expression has changed after it was checked” Angular popup error

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have seen couple of articles about this error, I have went through some but couldn't find the solution. Here i am calling alert method when my Boolean is true. The alert is coming perfectly when boolen is true but getting error in console.

**Error:**
"ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'."

Comment: Please post youe textual error as text.

Comment: @trichetriche done, Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be an error in your form controls. Consider changing `ngAfterViewInit` to `ngAfterContentChecked`, or surround all of the inner code of `ngAfterViewInit` with a timeout.

Comment: @trichetriche tried no use, same error.

Comment: Even with a timeout ?

Comment: @trichetriche Yes tried with timeout

Answer (score 6):

Use ChangeDetectorRef Service to force change Detection

When a view uses the OnPush (checkOnce) change detection strategy, explicitly marks the view as changed so that it can be checked again.

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: 'component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})


   constructor(cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){} 
   ngAfterViewInit() {
            let controlBlurs: Observable<any>[] = this.formControls
                .map((formControl: ElementRef) => Observable.fromEvent(formControl.nativeElement, 'blur'));
    // debounceTime(1000)/
            Observable.merge(this.orderUnitForm.valueChanges, ...controlBlurs).subscribe(value => {
                this.displayMessage = this.genericValidator.processMessages(this.orderUnitForm);
               // this.valid = this.genericValidator.validateControls(this.orderUnitForm);
            });
            this.orderUnitForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(1000).subscribe(value => {
                this.valid = this.genericValidator.validateControls(this.orderUnitForm);
                this.commaSeparation = this.genericValidator.validateMultiComma(this.orderUnitForm);
                  if(this.commaSeparation == true){
                    this.displayModel();
                  }
            });
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to detect changes is using ChangeDetectorRef in ngAfterContentChecked

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: 'component.html'
})
export class ComponentName implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked {
  constructor(private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  ...
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  ...
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this._cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```