# Angular Selected Option ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

```
<select [(ngModel)]="maritalStatus.code" ></select>
<option [value]="1" >Unmarried</option>
<option [value]="3" >Divorced</option>
<option [value]="2" >Married</option>
```

When i choose one of them, i want to show inputs and set required like this-

```
<div *ngIf="maritalStatus.code===2">
  <label> Marriage Date </label>

  <input type="date" #mDate="ngModel" 
  [required]="maritalStatus.code===2" 
  [(ngModel)]="marriageDate"  [ngClass]="{'is-valid':mDate.valid,'is- 
  invalid':mDate.invalid}" > 

  <div *ngIf="mDate.invalid">
  This field is required.
  </div>

</div>

<div *ngIf="maritalStatus.code===3">
   <label> Divorce Date </label>

   <input type="date" #dDate="ngModel" [required]="maritalStatus.code===3" 
   [(ngModel)]="divorceDate" [ngClass]="{'is-valid':dDate.valid,'is- 
  invalid':dDate.invalid}"  > 

   <div *ngIf="Date.invalid">
  This field is required.
  </div>

</div>
```

When i change the selected option, this error occurs:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'is-valid: true'.
>   Current value: 'is-valid: false.

Note: I am using BS4.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709592/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-angular-popup-error/51712109#51712109

Comment: Works for me. Thank you!