# HttpInterceptor causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when close MatDialog on handle pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have a spinner in a dialog component that I want to display before and after a http request were performed, the dialog open and close as expected but it always throws an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in the request response that I intercept in the handle.pipe.

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router, private sessionService: SessionService, private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const spinner = this.dialog.open(SpinnerDialogComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      autoFocus: true,
      width: '150px',
      height: '150px',
      panelClass: 'spinner'});

      ...

      const authReq = req.clone({ headers: headers});

      return next.handle(authReq).pipe(tap(
        (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            spinner.close();
          }
          return event;
        }));
  }
}
```

I'm working with angular6

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709592/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-angular-popup-error/51712109#51712109

Comment: could you post the whole error

Comment: MatDialogModule:1
    stack:"Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has 
    changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'id: undefined'. Current value: 'id: 
    mat-dialog-1'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its 
    children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection 
    hook ?\n    at viewDebugError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:60615:15)\n    at 
    expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError 
    (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:60603:12)\n    at checkBindingNoChanges

Comment: @Chellappan that didn't work for me, maybe because I'm using a simple object?, I just have an Injectable annotation there instead of a Component, is just a service and there is no lifecycle for it. I tried different solution even move this to a component but then I get different errors so I came back with this again