# disableRipple on mat-select cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I add disableRipple on a mat-select element I get a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

My code:

```
<mat-form-field>
          <mat-select [(value)]="selectedNumOption" disableRipple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of resultNumOptions" [value]="option">{{ option }}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The error:

```
MatOption.html:1 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
    at viewDebugError (core.es5.js:8433)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.es5.js:8411)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.es5.js:8575)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.es5.js:12418)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.es5.js:12390)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.es5.js:13183)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13085)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MatOption.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13067)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.es5.js:12230)
```

Removing disableRipple works, but why would disabling an animation create that type of error?

Also, is there a workaround to disable the select animation without disableRiple property?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709592/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-angular-popup-error/51712109#51712109

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz showing the error being thrown? Can you show some of the component code?