# Angular 6 - Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and trying to combine with [easyui angular](https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation2/index.php).

I found this error when trying to open/close dialog:

> **ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'klass: l-btn
>   f-inline-row f-content-center l-btn-small l-btn-focus'. Current value:
>   'klass: l-btn f-inline-row f-content-center l-btn-small'.**

And here is my code.

**user.component.html**

```
<eui-linkbutton (click)="addAction()" iconCls="icon-add" style="margin-bottom:10px">Add New</eui-linkbutton>
<eui-datagrid 
  [data]="users" style="height1:250px" [filterable]="true" 
  [selectionMode]="'single'"
  [(selection)]="rowSelected"
  [euiContextMenu]="contextMenu"
  >

</eui-datagrid>


<!-- contextmenu -->
<eui-menu #contextMenu (itemClick)="contextClick($event)">
    <eui-menu-item value="edit" text="Edit"></eui-menu-item>
    <eui-menu-item text="Delete"></eui-menu-item>
    <eui-menu-item text="View"></eui-menu-item>
</eui-menu>


<eui-dialog #formDialog [closed]="closed" [draggable]="true" [modal]="true" [title]="isNewRow ? 'Add' : 'Edit'" (close)="closed=true">

  <div class="dialog-button">
    <eui-linkbutton [disabled]="!formObj.valid" (click)="saveAction()" style="width:80px">Save</eui-linkbutton>
    <eui-linkbutton (click)="formDialog.close()" style="width:80px">Cancel</eui-linkbutton>
  </div>
</eui-dialog>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  rowSelected = null;
  formObj: FormGroup;

  constructor(public userService: UserService, fb: FormBuilder){

    }

  get row(){
      return this.rowSelected;
  }
  set row(value: any){
      this.rowSelected = value;
      this.formObj.reset(this.rowSelected);
  }

  editAction(row){
    this.row = this.rowSelected;
    this.closed = false;
  }

  addAction(){
    console.log('open babe');
    this.row = {
      'id' : null,
      'username' : null,
      'password' : null,
      'email' : null,
      'first_name' : null,
      'last_name' : null
    };

    this.closed = false;
  }


  isNewRow = false;
  editingRow = null;
  closed = true;
  users: Object;

  currentSelection = null;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getData().subscribe(
      data => this.users = data
    ) 
    console.log('ngoninit');

    this.initRow();
    this.closed = true;
  }

  initRow() {
    this.editingRow = {
      username: null,
      password: null,
      email: null,
      first_name: null,
      last_name: null,
    };
  }

  onAddRow() {
    console.log('open babe');
    this.initRow();
    this.isNewRow = true;
    this.closed = false;
  }

  onEditRow(row) {
    this.isNewRow = false;
    this.editingRow = row;
    this.closed = false;
  }
   contextClick(value){
    if(!this.rowSelected){
      alert('Please select a row first!');
    }
    else{
      if(value == 'edit'){
        this.editAction(this.rowSelected);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have search many tutorial to fix this problem but it seems like the tutorial condition doesn't match with mine.

Do i misunderstand something or missing something practical about angular?
what is the proper way to update attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709592/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-angular-popup-error/51712109#51712109

Comment: `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` put it in afterContentInit or ngDocheck Apart from this you would get this error during development Phase not in production cuz angular runs x2 change detection cycles in dev mode

Comment: @Vikas Agreed with the point that this happens only in dev mode, but this warning or error has to be taken care, else that would lead to inconsistent data binding between the components in production.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Yeah I  completely agree with you mate:)

Answer (score 22):

Use `ChangeDetectorRef` Service to detect new changes

When a view uses the `OnPush` (checkOnce) **change detection strategy**, explicitly marks the view as changed so that it can be checked again.

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: 'component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

})


   constructor(cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){} 
   ngAfterViewInit() {

     this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      }
```

Comment: i tried this,but same error still occur, plus my app seems laggy and unresponsive when taking action.

Comment: i'm sorry sir, i tried it again but same result.
one point here is my app is running well, but that error log in developer tool that bugs me.

Comment: like this?
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'klass: l-btn f-inline-row f-content-center l-btn-small l-btn-focus'. Current value: 'klass: l-btn f-inline-row f-content-center l-btn-small'.

Answer (score 12):

I was getting this error after modifying a `Map` object that was being iterated over using

```
*ngFor="let entry of myMap.entries()"
```

The fix that worked for me was just to add `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to my component declaration:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: 'component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Can't able to see the open/close dialog code. Here is explanation for the issue. Usually Angular Updates the DOM based on Model object with help of Change Detection. Angular updates the DOM and it got reflected in UI, After that Model also got updated.

Angular don't know what needs to do, so it's reporting an error. We need to manually trigger the change detection in order to reflect the DOM. Try to wrap the section of code inside setTimeout Block

```
setTimeout(()=>{

});
```

Comment: im trying to include all my code, but form SO system reject my question and said my code is too much(something like that). so i remove some of it, and seems like i over do it

Comment: which section i need to wrap?

Comment: the function you are calling to open dialog

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is you are initializing form for users. So the issue is that the form is building first and then users are getting loaded so angular is detecting changes so it's throwing an error. Ideally **this.cdRef.detectChanges();** should work. Also I have added a check in **HTML** that component will load only after users list are fetched from service.

This might help you :

**TS :**

```
     constructor(cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef,public userService: UserService, fb: FormBuilder){
     }

     ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.getData().subscribe(
          data => {
             this.users = data;
             this.initRow();
             this.cdRef.detectChanges();
          }
        ); 
        console.log('ngoninit');
        this.closed = true;
      }
```

**HTML :**

```
 <eui-datagrid *ngIf="users && users.length > 0"
      [data]="users" style="height1:250px" [filterable]="true" 
      [selectionMode]="'single'"
      [(selection)]="rowSelected"
      [euiContextMenu]="contextMenu" >
```

Comment: You could add some description to explain how this code will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for the answer to this, I finally found a solution!

I was getting this error and resolved it by adding **this.changeDetector.detectChanges()** to **ngAfterViewInit()**.

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

...

export class ClassName implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {

  ...

  constructor(
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    // Code here to populate fields, which are bound
    // in the html, from within a Subscription.
    // This was the source of my error.
  }

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

After implementing the above code, the error disappeared! See the following link for more details:

https://gist.github.com/vades/a225170304f34f88a7a5d48bf4b1f58c