# Expression has changed after it was checked-using @ViewChild reference

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Hi I am using this context menu component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-contextmenu
when I am binding the [contextMenu]="basicMenu"
like this, and using the basicMenu with

```
@ViewChild(ContextMenuComponent)
public basicMenu:ContextMenuComponent
```

I get the following error:
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasCheckedError: Previous Value:
'contextMenu:undefined'.Current value:'contextMenu[object Object]'

I know that the error is cause becuase the value is changed before the view is initialized in the middle of the process that runs the hooks.So I tried to run the change detection in the ngAfterViewInit with changeDetectorRef, however it doesnt work either...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
@ViewChild(ContextMenuComponent, { static: true }) public basicMenu: ContextMenuComponent;
```

I think there were some breaking changes with @ViewChild in Angular 9.

Comment: can you explain what does it do ?  it gives me only the read property

Comment: This should make it available in `ngOnInit` instead of the `ngAfterViewInit` and no worries, I think you're on an older version of Angular. I am not sure how to fix this issue, maybe something with the library?

Comment: what do you mean by making it available on onInit? can you supply the full code ? excuse my ignorance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359504/how-should-i-use-the-new-static-option-for-viewchild-in-angular-8

Read the first answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922326/angular-6-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked Try the first answer here as well but I am not sure how clean/sustainable that is though.

Comment: thank you so much! I am in angular 7, so I cant use the static property ?

Comment: Yes, I think it is not available in version 7. I think it was introduced in version 8.

Comment: I will try to upgrade.. meanwhile I used the ngAfterContentChecked hook and then forced another change detection whith changeDetectorRef